Exclude Mock data referenced from Xcode Previews for Archive build
I'm trying to use the PreviewContent folder to exclude Mock assets that I'm only using in my previews. The code below builds as expected until I try to build an archive. Then I get: "Cannot find 'MockData' in scope".
Using XCode16 default project settings.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    let mockData = MockData()
    ContentView(text: mockData.text)
}

The MockData.swift file placed in the 'Preview Content' contains:
struct MockData {
    let text = "Hello, Mock Data!"
}

How can I use MockData in my previews, which are excluded from my final archive?

There is a workaround to achieve, wrapping #Preview within #if DEBUG:
#if DEBUG
#Preview {
    let mockData = MockData()
    ContentView(text: mockData.text)
}
#endif

As Apple staff mentioned here and here.

#Preview and its predecessor PreviewProvider tend to get dead code stripped when building for release, but there are projects where lingering references might cause them to stick around. Best way to be sure they are only present in debug builds would be to wrap the definitions like so:

